# Не могу установить модуль дискорд Python "discord" (pip install discord.py)

Tags: python

Сама ошибка выскакивает после:

```
C:\Users\Home-PC>pip install discord.py
Collecting discord.py
  Using cached discord.py-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (699 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0
  Using cached aiohttp-3.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (441 kB)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0
  Using cached yarl-1.6.0.tar.gz (175 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting chardet<4.0,>=2.0
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
  Using cached attrs-20.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting multidict<5.0,>=4.5
  Using cached multidict-4.7.6.tar.gz (50 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting idna>=2.0
  Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: yarl, multidict
  Building wheel for yarl (PEP 517) ... error 


ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\home-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\home-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Home-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\tmph4rbw5ga'
           cwd: C:\Users\Home-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3thavqw8\yarl
      Complete output (35 lines):
      **********************
      * Accellerated build *
      **********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
      copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
      copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
      running egg_info
      writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
      copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
      running build_ext
      building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
      Building wheel for multidict (PEP 517) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\home-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\home-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Home-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9bha4p8h'
           cwd: C:\Users\Home-PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3thavqw8\multidict
      Complete output (40 lines):
      **********************
      * Accellerated build *
      **********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
      copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
      copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
      copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
      copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
      copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
      running egg_info
      writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
      copying multidict\_multidict.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
      copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
      copying multidict\_multilib\defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
      copying multidict\_multilib\dict.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
      copying multidict\_multilib\istr.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
      copying multidict\_multilib\iter.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
      copying multidict\_multilib\pair_list.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
      copying multidict\_multilib\views.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
      running build_ext
      building 'multidict._multidict' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
    Failed to build yarl multidict
    ERROR: Could not build wheels for yarl, multidict which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: Вроде причина очевидна - не хватает компилятора C для сборки зависимостей.

Comment: Что мне нужно сделать? 
я в этом не разбираюсь..
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64250866/7485582. Понизьте версию питона до 3.8

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
> ```

⇒ Надо [поставить](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0

Answer (score 1):

пробуйте pip install wheel, или обновить pip (python —m pip install —upgrade pip)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй в cmd прописать python -m install pip discord

Comment: Неправильный ответ.